# mysql: contain in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am facing issue with database query. 
Here is the query which i have at the moment.

```
SELECT tn_id,title,content,type,post_as,city, state,country,pincode,datetime FROM user_posts 
    where deleted = 0 and state like "%delhi ncr%" order by datetime DESC  limit 15
```

Now you can see i am using like in query for state name. In database value is written 'Delhi'. When i run the query it is returning 0 records.
Seems like **like** is not going to use in this situation.

I am not sure how can i fix this issue.

I also tried **INSTR(name, 'foo')**

Comment: Did you try `state like "%Delhi%ncr%"` ?

Comment: yes i did. no luck 0 records returning.

Comment: What do you get when you try `like "%delhi%"`?

Comment: i am getting all the corresponding records.

Comment: I assume some of those records have a state that is `delhi ncr`?

Comment: Your `LIKE` clause can have _fewer_ letters than the desired record, but not _more_.  If the desired record is just "Delhi", you should not expect it to match a search that also has " ncr"

Comment: is there any way to perform the match? Because it can happen.

Comment: @MrGlass no records have delhi ncr mentioned.

Comment: You're going to want to do research on `FULLTEXT` searches

Comment: @Ironic, then your `like` will not return any records. If I may ask, why do you have `like "%delhi ncr%"` when you have no records that will match that query?

Comment: I got the answer guys. I need to use locate command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it fixed by using locate keyword.

```
SELECT tn_id,title,content,type,post_as,city, state,country,pincode,longitude,latitude,datetime,full_location FROM user_posts 
    where deleted = 0 and locate(state, '%Delhi ncr%') order by datetime DESC  limit 15
```

Hope it helps someone.